# How do I prevent an argument to a javascript function being retained by a closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

***EDIT:* The context for this question is, the argument is the source string for a module being loaded which could be huge, and there are many many modules being loaded this way, and each one has a closure with the original source code of the module held within it, using memory, when its not needed or wanted.**

**Specifically, I am trying to fix this https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/dojo.js#L367 code which leaks the module source into the closure.**

```
<script>
function closureTest(n) {
    function eval_(__text) {
        return eval(__text);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var m = eval_("(function(){ var x = 10; return function(n) { return x+n; }; })(window);");
        m(5);
    }
}
</script>
<button onclick="closureTest(1000)">Run</button>
```

In the above code, if a breakpoint is placed inside the anonymous function, and the closures that exist are examined, we can see that one of the closures contains __text and arguments[0] that contains the original source code of the module as it was passed to eval_

Here is a variation of the above:

```
<script>
function closureTest(n) {
    function eval_() {
        return eval(arguments[0]);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var m = eval_("(function(){ var x = 10; return function(n) { return x+n; }; })(window);");
        m(5);
    }
}
</script>
<button onclick="closureTest(1000)">Run</button>
```

In this case, the closure no longer contains __text but does still contain arguments[0] with the string passed to eval_.

About the best I could come up with is the following, which deletes the argument to eval_ after processing it, a side effect is that the module being defined now also appears in the closure as a variable called module.

```
<script>
function closureTest(n) {
    function eval_() {
        var module = eval(arguments[0]);
        delete arguments[0];
        return module;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var m = eval_("(function(){ var x = 10; return function(n) { return x+n; }; })(window);");
        m(5);
    }
}
</script>
<button onclick="closureTest(1000)">Run</button>
```

Is there a better way to prevent the closure retaining a copy of the argument passed to eval_?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish here. Why do you want to get rid of `arguments[0]`? Can you provide some more details? Thanks!

Comment: This is a sufficiently weird thing to want to do that some context really should be supplied in the question.

Comment: Why are you using the eval_ function and not the native eval function directly? Are you planning to implement more logic on that function?

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT] Completely missed the point of the question.**

**Short answer: You cannot.** As you are aware, a closure maintains the environment state from which it was created; there's no way to "break out" of a closure scope hierarchy.

When you call `m()` you are not calling it within a global context, but rather part of a chain of environments of, not only the `eval_` closure but also `closureTest` as well -- You can see your returned eval'ed function also has access to the `i` and `n` vars defined in `closureTest`.

So, you cannot restrict or break out of a closure. However, if you define a *new variable in your new scope* with the same name as a variable from a previous closure you lose direct access to that. Therfore, your middle example is as close as you can get:

```
function closureTest(n) {
    function eval_() {
        return eval(arguments[0]);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var m = eval_("(function(){ var x = 10; return function(n) { return x+n; }; })(window);");
        m(5);
    }
 }
```

Here, your returned eval'ed function cannot access `eval_`'s arguments since it's own `arguments` have overridden it (it does, however, still have access to  `i` and `n` from the for loop). This means, functionally, that eval'ed string cannot access the arguments passed to `eval_`.

Notes:

- Yes, when you set a breakpoint in DevTools you can inspect the parent closures however *that does not impact the fact that the executing function cannot directly access `eval_`'s `arguments[0]*.
- Also, the function *could* get the string of the upper functions using `arguments.callee.caller.toString();` etc. This still doesn't allow the function direct access to redefined vars, but thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: you missed the point of the question, forget the value being returned, the point of the question is how to avoid the source code passed to eval from being retained in a closure

Comment: Nice answer, but I don't want to hide the argument, I want to release it, free it from memory.  I should have made that clearer in the question.